# How to add new input to the configuration file using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redhat, archlinux

I want to add new input to the configuration file from terminal using bash script. This is what I tried:

```
echo Hello, please add the new text here
read varname
sed -i "s/\<my-images=>/& $varname/" /home/myconfig
echo Image $varname has been added to the configuration. Thanks!!
```

/home/myconfig has

```
id=1
max-mb=1000
my-images=customimage
```

And required output is

```
id=1
max-mb=1000
my-images=mynewtext customimage
```

So mynewtext should be added after my-images= 
Anyway to do this?

Comment: What happens when you run your solution?

Comment: No Change. Remains the same. @robinsax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the regex match you're passing to `sed`. Try:

```sh
sed -i "s/my-images=/&$varname /" /home/myconfig
```

instead.

Comment: When I enter my input as testthat/version1  it throws me an error. Error is :: Hello,please add the new text here
testthat/version1
sed: -e expression #1, char 38: unknown option to `s'    How to pass raw input? I tried using read -r -p "Enter Input 'Enter the text >>>' varname @robinsax

Comment: Without formatting I have no idea what that error is, but it's probably because the `/` makes the `sed` regex invalid. You'll need to escape `/`s prior to inserting them into the `sed` regex.